# Is there a better way to DELETE 80 million+ rows from a table?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a better way to DELETE 80 million+ rows from a table?

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM large_table)
    BEGIN
        WITH LT AS
            (
                SELECT TOP 60000 *
                FROM large_table
            )
        DELETE FROM LT
    END
```

This does the job of keeping my transaction logs from becoming too large, but I need to know if there is a way to make this process go faster? I've had my computer on for 5+ days now running this script and I haven't gotten very far, very fast.

Comment: Can't you just use [`TRUNCATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql)? Are you deleting all rows?

Comment: You could maybe find this article by Aaron Bertrand helpful: [Break large delete operations into chunks](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes)

Comment: 5+ DAYS?!?! wtf... Do you have triggers on your table? Is this running on your toaster?

Comment: Check Aaron Bertrand's article. Batched deletes will *always* be slower than one big delete. Batching is used to keep the transaction log small. To keep it small though you have to back it up after each batch so the relevant records are released

Comment: There are many ways to delete but you need to work out what's slowing it down. Lack of indexes? too many indexes? Foreign Keys (FK's seriously slow it down). Triggers? Underpowered machine? I suggest you use `sp_WhoIsActive` to work out what it's waiting on. How many rows are left when you've deleted? Maybe just insert those into a new table and rename them both

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid -- Please find my reply, Too many indexes? Yes I have 7-8 Indexes, but that required for daily use,
Foreign Keys (FK's seriously slow it down). Yes primary key of the main table is linked with almost 15 tables,
Triggers? No, I don't have any trigger,
Underpowered machine? No, High-end server with 128 GB Ram, 
I suggest you use sp_WhoIsActive to work out what it's waiting on. How to use sp_WhoIsActive?
How many rows are left when you've deleted? I have not tried batch delete, 
Maybe just insert those into a new table and rename them both. Renaming is Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the table simply by.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE large_table
GO
```

You can also use delete by using where condition. The time taken by delete depends on various aspects. You can reduce the cost by eliminating SELECT query in the condition of WHILE loop.

```
DECLARE @rows INT = 1

WHILE (@rows>0)
BEGIN

   DELETE TOP 1000 *
   FROM large_table

   @rows = @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

Comment: But my transaction logs file increasing rapidly, How can I stop log process?

Comment: You may create a job doing above process running at fix interval of time.

Comment: But my transaction logs becoming too large and process getting stopped.

Comment: You can also truncate the table. I have changed the code as well. Check again.

Comment: @Tripurari in order to truncate the transaction log you have to back it up. Rigerta Demiri posted the relevant article by Aaron Bertrand to the question comments a week ago. Did you try it? Why aren't you truncating the table anyway? Or use partition switching and just *drop* the old data?

Comment: @TripurariYadav : Yes He is right. You can Try truncating the table. The solution below it was considering any condition you have for deleting rows.

Comment: I have tried all solution but I got failed. I can not truncate table because it's my live database. I need to delete old records only. I need 1-year data in the system.

Answer (score -1):

Bulk deletion will create a lots of logs and rollback happen if the log file is full.

you can do the delete as batches and ensure every transaction is committed.

```
DECLARE @IDCollection TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @Batch INT = 1000;
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT;

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO @IDCollection
    SELECT TOP (@Batch) ID
    FROM table
    ORDER BY id

    DELETE
    FROM table
    WHERE id IN (
            SELECT *
            FROM @IDCollection
            )

    SET @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT


    IF (@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Comment: The table variable will *not* improve speed. The transaction will *not* clean up the transaction log. The only way to clean it up after each batch, is to back it up

Comment: Check [Break large delete operations into chunks](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes). You *have* to perform either `CHECKPOINT` or `BACKUP LOG` after each iteration

Comment: Set the recovery model of the database to simple until the operation is completed

Comment: And it will *still* get logged. Read the article. As for the table variable - moving the IDs to tempdb is what the optimizer would do with `DELETE TOP N ` anyway. Table variables are *not* stored in memory. Even if they were, they would *not* be faster without an index.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - How can I perform either CHECKPOINT or BACKUP LOG after each iteration?